# iOS objectmapper, mapping json with array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I have a simple question:  how to convert such a json response to object with usage of Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

```
{
   "errors": [
      {
         "code": "404",
         "message": "Wrong id"
      }
    ]
}
```

With swiftyJson i do

```
json["errors"][0]["code"]
```

but how to do it with objectmapper ? i tried this:

```
map["errors.code"]
```

and it does not work

EDIT: i did Error and ErrorResponse clasess like suggested, now:

```
//...
    let fullAddress = mainAddress + additionalAddr
    var parameters = ["email":email]

    manager.GET( fullAddress,
        parameters: parameters,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            //here is success, i got it done with user mapping
            callback(success: true)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in

            let errorResponse = Mapper<ErrorResponse>().map(operation.responseString!)


            println(errorResponse!) //this prints: MyApp.ErrorResponse
            println(errorResponse?.errors!) //this prints: Optional([MyApp.Error]) 
            println(errorResponse?.errors![0]) //this prints:Optional(MyApp.Error)
            println(errorResponse?.errors![0].code) //<- this is nil :(
           // how to get the code mapped ?
            callback(success: false)
     })
}
```

Comment: it gives type of expression is amigous without more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the property `errors` is an array, and ObjectMapper try to convert it to an object.

For the JSON you have provided, the correct answer is as follow:

```
class Error: Mappable, Printable {
    var code: String?
    var message: String?

    init() {}

    class func newInstance() -> Mappable {
        return Error()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.code <- map["code"]
        self.message <- map["message"]
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: false)!
        }
    }
}

class ErrorResponse: Mappable, Printable {
    var errors: [Error]?

    init () {}

    class func newInstance() -> Mappable {
        return ErrorResponse()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.errors <- map["errors"]
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: false)!
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    let json = "{\"errors\": [{\"code\": \"404\",\"message\": \"Wrong id\"}]}"

    let errorResponse = Mapper<ErrorResponse>().map(json)

    println("errorResponse: \(errorResponse?.description)")

    if let errors = errorResponse?.errors {
        println("errors: \(errors.description)")
        println("errors[0] \(errors[0])")
        println("errors[0].code \(errors[0].code)")
        println("errors.first!.message \(errors.first!.message)")
    }
```

Output:

```
errorResponse: Optional("{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Wrong id\",\"code\":\"404\"}]}")
errors: [{"message":"Wrong id","code":"404"}]
errors[0] {"message":"Wrong id","code":"404"}
errors[0].code Optional("404")
errors.first!.message Optional("Wrong id")
```

Comment: It partially works: let errorResponse = Mapper<ErrorResponse>().map(operation.responseString!), then i get object of ErrorResponse, with array of [Error] object as you said. However when i do something like that errorResponse.errors.first.code  - then it says nil. Shall i do some additional mapping ?

Comment: @Ammo it works for me, btw I added a test to prove that it works

Comment: @Ammo I tested your code with `println(errorResponse?.errors![0].code)`
and it works. I think that the response code is `nil`, or you are missing something

Comment: yeah thank you for the help, the problem with code was that json was actually like that (code is not passed as a string) : "errors": [
      {
         "code": 404,
         "message": "Wrong id"
      }
    ]

Answer (score 0):

Should only pass the JSON-String and not a String you hand wrote to the map function.

From the [README](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper):

> Once your class implements Mappable, the Mapper class handles everything else for you:
>
> Convert a JSON string to a model object:

```
let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONString)
```

So your scenario could be:

```
let error = Mapper<Error>().map(json)
```